# Deleting an answer from suggested edit review queue deletes all the answers & the question

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, review

An [answer](https://superuser.com/a/463683/4377) was flagged for deletion citing duplication of existing answer, and there was a suggested edit on the same answer.

Since the duplicate answer wasn't needed, I hit the delete post option from the suggested edit review queue  and then the system proceeded to ask me few times(I believe equal to number of posts) if I wanted to delete the post, and then proceeded to delete **all** the answers and the question.

I'm not sure why it proceeded to delete all the posts, since the delete option was asked only for that specific post as part of review. Further more, the question was also locked prior to deletion, so I had to [unlock it after undeleting it](https://superuser.com/posts/114129/revisions).

Comment: Ah, the new "delete all the things" mod feature is finally here! It was a long wait, but definitely worth it!

Comment: Next: deleting a user causes all the site's users to be deleted.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the migration from SO to SU might have to do something with it. It could see anonymous users / posts from SO different in one or another way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ouch. This bug only occurred when deleting via the suggested edit review queue *from the question page*. That is, you have to had clicked the "edit (1)" link beneath the post. Deleting from `/review` worked as expected. And obviously (and thankfully), it only affected mods.

It's fixed now. Thank you for fixing up the post in question when you realized what happened.

Comment: ah. Thanks for fixing!